# Developing windows forms applications?

Tags: c++, windows, forms

C++ is by far my language of choice. However, I have only developed libraries and console applications.

I like how in Visual C# you can easily design a GUI for your application - simple drag-and-drop controls and edit their properties simply.

I have tried to create a windows form application in Visual C++, but it uses the CLR/.Net. Is there a way to make a windows form application in Visual Studio without having to use the CLR or .Net? I really love how easy it is to design a form application in C# or VB.NET.

Thanks!

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to... say... MFC.

Comment: MFC isn't so bad, You can always go right to Windows API or use some nifty cross platform framework like Qt or wxWidgets.

Comment: i almost believe the functionality he's looking for is in the visual studio resource editor, he might want to look into creating dialog based applications with something like MFC, or ATL/WTL.

Comment: Windows Forms is a .NET technology, it requires the .NET framework.  You can use C++/CLI to program in C++ and still get all of the convenience of Windows Forms.  Is there something specific about the .NET framework you have an aversion to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the whole concept of a .NET application is that it leverages the .NET framework to do all the cool stuff you mentioned.  If you were to elaborate on what it is you are trying to accomplish we may could recommend an alternative solution, but if you write a C# winForms application it's going to need the .NET framework to run...

EDIT:

You could use a qt ide, or possibly a QT plugin for visual studio.  Check this thread out:
[Best QT ide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427965/best-qt-ide)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, sorry for not being clear. I want to develop a C++ windows forms application WITHOUT .Net. Mainly I just want the "drag-and-drop" simplicity of the form designer in Visual Studio, but with C++ as my language.